# Is Date.today in UTC?

Tags: ruby, date, timezone

Calling `Date.today` in Ruby returns the current date.  However, what timezone is it in?  I assume UTC, but I want to make sure.  The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today) doesn't state either way.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `Date.today` uses the system’s local time zone. If you require it be in UTC, instead get the date from a UTC time, e.g. `Time.now.utc.to_date`.

---

Dates do not have timezones, since they don't represent a time.

That said, as for *how* it calculates the current day, let's look at this extract from [the code for `Date.today`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_125/ext/date/date_core.c#L3609):

```
time_t t;
struct tm tm;
// ...
if (time(&t) == -1)
  rb_sys_fail("time");
if (!localtime_r(&t, &tm))
  rb_sys_fail("localtime");
```

It then proceeds to use use `tm` to create the `Date` object. Since `tm` contains the system's local time using [`localtime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime), `Date.today` therefore uses the system's local time, not UTC.

---

You can always use [`Time#utc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-utc) on any `Time` convert it in-place to UTC, or [`Time#getutc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-getutc) to return a new equivalent `Time` object in UTC. You could then call [`Time#to_date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-to_date) on that to get a `Date`. So: `some_time.getutc.to_date`.

If you’re using [ActiveSupport’s time zone support](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) (included with Rails), note that it is completely separate from Ruby’s time constructors and does not affect them (i.e. it does not change how `Time.now` or `Date.today` work). See also [ActiveSupport extensions to `Time`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-time).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I guess a better way to ask my question would have been "in conjunction with which time zone does Date.today return the next day?"  I suppose if I want "today's date in UTC", I'll need to do something like `Time.now.zone.to_date` (in Rails).

Comment: `Time.zone.now.to_date` will use whatever time zone the application is configured to. It's worth looking into `Time.use_zone('[zone name]')` in case you want to set the time zone for a specific block of code, in this case to UTC.

Comment: Yes with ActiveSupport’s time zone management, you can do `Time.zone.now.to_date` which equals `Time.current.to_date` which equals `Date.current`.

Answer (score 58):

You can get away by using

`Time.now.utc.to_date`

in ruby

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer. I wonder if this was added since April 2012.

Comment: this is useful info, but it doesnt answer the question. this answers the related question "how can i get the date of the current UTC time?", the poster asked whether Date.today was in UTC or not, not how to get the date in utc.

Answer (score 11):

An instance of Date is represented as an Astronomical Julian Day Number; it has no fractional part of a day. While a Julian Day is relative to GMT - so technically an instance of Date should be considered to be in GMT - for most purposes you can ignore that and treat it as having no timezone. You would only care about a time zone if you converted it to a DateTime or Time.

ActiveSupport's tools for date conversion let you specify whether you want local time or UTC.

E.g.:

```
>> t = Date.today.to_time
=> Wed Apr 18 00:00:00 -0400 2012
>> t.zone
=> "EDT"
>> t = Date.today.to_time(:utc)
=> Wed Apr 18 00:00:00 UTC 2012
>> t.zone
=> "UTC"
```

Comment: See the comment I made on @AndrewMarshall's answer regarding why I asked the original question.  Basically, I'm trying to figure out if Date.today on the local system would be the same as Date.today on a system in UTC.

Comment: As Andrew says, Date.today does generate a date from the local time not UTC.

To get the date corresponding to the time in UTC, try Time.now.utc.to_date

Comment: I'd just point out that whilst for some countries, ignoring a date's timezone might work, here in NZ you get the wrong date for most of the working day if you do that. (e.g 10am local on the 13th Feb is, I think, 2100 UTC on the 12th).

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Date.current
```

To get the current date on the configured timezone.

Answer (score 2):

If your rails applications is configured to run in time zone UTC then just use `Time.zone.today`, otherwise force it by using `Time.now.utc.to_date`

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby

```
# Using local timezone
Date.today
```

### Ruby on Rails

```
# Using UTC
Date.yesterday
Date.current
Date.tomorrow
```

This is specifically nasty because when using e.g. `Date.today` and `Date.yesterday` in conjunction, it might produce quite unexpected results depending on the timezone and the current time.

For example, at 00:30 in timezone CET (UTC+1) `Date.yesterday` will be two days before `Date.today`. In other cases, `Date.today` and `Date.yesterday` can have the same value.