# Date class returns same for today and tomorrow - Weird and Intriguing bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

[image: WEIRD]

Our rspec was having weird behaviour as in the night between 12 and 5 a.m., our tests were falling. (I live in India, GMT + 5.30)

On inspecting further, this is what I saw

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)
[1] pry(main)> Date.yesterday
=> Thu, 09 Apr 2015
[2] pry(main)> Date.today
=> Sat, 11 Apr 2015
[3] pry(main)> Date.tomorrow
=> Sat, 11 Apr 2015
[4] pry(main)>
```

Using Ruby 2.1, and Rails 4.1.8

To me it seems like Date.yesterday and Date.tomorrow is computed based on Date.current (and without timezone it is assumed to be UTC). Date.today is computed differently and current timezone pictures in.

Does this imply that I should not be using any time, dates without explicit timezone. Isn't this just plain wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

At the very least, I found this as an interesting find from someone in our team

Comment: What time zone are you setting in your application config? And to follow up, what time zone is the machine serving your app using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219670/is-date-today-in-utc), `Date.today` uses the system's local time.

In unit tests, you should mock out time, but you should standardize on UTC in integration tests. You can use `Time.now.utc.to_date` to do that. [ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-local_to_utc) can help you out as well.

Answer (score 1):

So I played a little, wasn't hard to find apparently...

Now, I did the same thing on irb instead of the rails console, after I required the 'Date' class. Thing is only Date.today exists, and other don't by default, which means Rails must have included it for our needs.

I read a bit on how they extended the Date class, thought I'd create a issue on github/rails, but then I stumbled onto this -: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12414

Summarizing it,  Date.today, should be replaced with Date.current , so this gives

```
[1] pry(main)> Date.today
=> Sat, 11 Apr 2015
[2] pry(main)> Date.current
=> Fri, 10 Apr 2015
```

Only Date.today is non inclusive of timezone, the other functions by Rails are.....The inconsistency is unexpected, and not nice.

Comment: I get that it isn't exactly intuitive, but you reveal the core issue when you say, "Date.today is non inclusive...the *other* functions by Rails are." To refer to the *other* functions in Rails implies `Date.today` is a function in Rails. It isn't; it's a function in *Ruby*. You just need to understand that it is common on every platform for the core language to have certain functions and for custom 3rd-party libraries to implement things differently. In this case though, the issue is mitigated by following established best practices on using dates in tests.