# Rails - Query records before or after 5AM today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I need to write a scope (or method) to query events based on the time of day - Basically I'd like to have "future" and "past" events - but at an offset that kicks in at 5AM.

The use case is a nightclub. At 1AM, the event is still going on, and the doorman still needs to use the event as if its up and coming. But by 5AM, the event is over, and the owners now want to see how it went.

I've got scopes like this (date is a datetime):

```
scope :future, -> { where("date >= ?", Date.today + 5.hours) }
scope :past, -> { where("date < ?", Date.today + 5.hours) }
```

That isn't working though. Does anyone have any insight on how I could do this?

EDIT: Always love the downvoters! I don't know how to put this more clearly. At 5AM on the event date, I want the event to fall into the past scope. Very simple question/problem. Have a great day haters.

Comment: You have two `scopes` with *same name*.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working at all?" What do you expect to be happening, and what is actually happening? Help us help you.

Comment: So if it is currently 1am, then the next four hours should count as "in the past"?

Comment: No, if it is 1AM, there is still 4 hours until its in the past. Think of a nightclub...the event still needs to show up for the doormen. But by 5AM, the event is done, and the owners want to see how it went.

Answer (score 0):

If rails is saving your time in UTC you could may be have a problem with time zones. You could try something like `Time.now.utc + 5.hours`.

Answer (score 0):

The Date.today method uses the system date and time functionality provided by the operating system so it is not a good practice to use it.

You should explicitly specify the timezone.

for more info see the answers to this question: [Is Date.today in UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219670/is-date-today-in-utc)